# Does Azure by default do any regional or output caching?

Tags: azure, azure-web-apps

I'm working on a website that is currently hosted on Microsoft's Azure cloud hosting service, and I noticed what appeared to be slightly different output for a user in a different region.  It seemed like we were looking at two different instances or at least he had cached output that took a few minutes to catch up with mine.

I know all about [Azure's autoscaling feature](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn589774.aspx), but **according to the autoscaling history graph there was only a single instance at the time.**  Furthermore the operation logs have no mention of autoscaling or anything else occurring.

So that leads me to wonder if there is some other form of caching or multiple instance creation that occurs by default in azure?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have local cache enabled on the app?

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-local-cache

By default Azure has no output caching, it would have to be enabled. Something like redis cache.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the response, appreciate it.  I did not see the app settings keys needed to trigger local caching, so it doesn't look like local caching is being used.